# How to email all contacts under an account from child object?

Tags: email-alert

We have a proposal object that is a child of the contact object which is a child of accounts.

To show is differently, Accounts-->Multiple Contacts-->One Proposal

If someone creates a proposal document, all contacts under the given account need to get an email alert.

I am not sure how to set this up. All I have is when a proposal is created, only one contact gets an email. That's not enough.

How does one accomplish this just with clicks? or must one use a trigger?

Thanks

Comment: Did a proposal document is a child object for contact or account please explain it briefly & mention your efforts about this requirement what you have done so far

Comment: I edited the question. Is it any clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using Flow? You can collect a list of emails using a Fast Lookup that grabs the Email address of all Contacts related to the Account ID and send an email through there.

Comment: Would you happen to know of an online tutorial that does this so I can get the "hang of it"?

Comment: I don't have a specific example but here's how you'd collect records then loop through them: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/vpm_designer_example_loop.htm